# Как в заголовках сетевого запроса преобразовать русские символы в требуемый вид

Tags: javascript, utf-8, axios

Я пытаюсь реализовать сетевой запрос при помощи axios JS. В самом запросе мне нужно указать заголовок для дайджест(digest)-аутентификации и при этом в нем есть русские символы, которые нужно преобразовать в требуемый вид.
Когда я пробую произвести аутентификацию через браузер, то он как я понял преобразует русские символы из UTF8 в win1252. 
Я создал пользователя "ру" и пытаюсь с ним войти. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы видим, что браузер сам формирует заголовок авторизации, где преобразует русские символы в "**Ñ€Ñƒ**" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Саму дайджест(digest)-аутентификацию при помощи JS я умею делать.
НО как реализовать конвертацию русских символов из **UTF8 в win1252 при помощи JavaScript**, чтобы на выходе был подобный формат "**Ñ€Ñƒ**", который я уже могу отправить? Я пытался сделать преобразования при помощи плагинов, но они выдают на выходе буфер, а не строку. Возможно, я вообще не туда копаю...

Comment: он не преобразует в нужный вид. Он из "ру" преобразует в "%u0440%u0443" а это неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за многочисленные ответы. В моем случае помогло следующее решение:

```
const inText = "ру";
const te = new TextEncoder();
const text = te.encode(inText );
const outText = String.fromCharCode(...text);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]